# About to work in a company that uses Team Foundation Server?Advice needed

Tags: tfs

As a developer I am a user of Subversion at the moment and I am changing job and going to work for a company that uses Team Foundation Server
I would like to  learn the basic and more as user of Team Foundation Server

What do I need to do to replicate the enviroment and practice a bit?

Any Tips ?

What should I read?

Can I simulate the enviroment?

Thanks  a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend reading this comprehensive document on codeplex: [Visual Studio TFS Branching Guide 2010](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/)

For simulation, without having to set eveything up, there are virtual labs here: [Team System Virtual Labs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/aa740411.aspx)

As an aside, it is also worth installing [TFS Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) and the [TFS Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963.aspx)

Comment: Thanks This will give me something to go on.